# Missing Class on import of TestNexusActions

Tags: nolio

Trying to import a DAT file in 5.0 containing TestNexusActions.
Error message says:
Problems encountered while importing application [TestNexusActions] :Import failure. the action [FolderLooppPreEvaluator] ID [1,799] Class [com.nolio.platform.shared.executables.actions.loops.FolderLoopPreEvaluator] does not exist in the system. you need to update your actions jars with this action class.

action jar nolio-nexus-actions-5.0-10.2.1402.7.jar has been imported and doesn't apprear to have other dependencies.

Can this issue be solved by imprting the listed class and if so where do I get the jar?

Answer (score 0):

Loop actions (Used by flow loops) sit in the main `nolio-actions-5.0.jar` and this specific class `FolderLoopPreEvaluator` is new to version 5.0.

This error usually occurs when trying to import a 5.0 DAT file in to a 4.7- environment (which is not supported). If this is not the case, make sure that you have the right version of the nolio-actions jar or maybe try to reload it from the action management console.